# javascript, if/else within reduce function not being satisfied properly

Tags: javascript

I have a snippet below where I'm reducing an object and at one point trying to create an array of skus and do a comparison on those skus with another object in order to set a status variable. I'm currently getting this output:

```
{
"joe": {
    "2020/03/03": {
        "sets": 4,
        "reps": 17,
        "total": 0,
        "skus": [
            {
                "123": []
            },
            "No stock found",
            {
                "234": []
            },
            "No stock found"
        ]
    }]
}
}
```

But I'm expecting more like this:

```
{
"joe": {
    "2020/03/03": {
        "sets": 4,
        "reps": 17,
        "total": 0,
        "skus": [
            {
              "123": [
                 "status": "Available"
              ],
               "234": [
                  "status": "Available"
              ]
            },

        ]
    },
    etc.
}
}
```

How would I fix this to get my desired output?

```js
const res = [
  { name: "joe", sku: 123, reps: 2, sets: 2, date: "2020/03/03" },
  { name: "joe", sku: 234, reps: 15, sets: 2, date: "2020/03/03" },
  { name: "joe", sku: 345, reps: 26, sets: 5, date: "2020/03/05" },
  { name: "joe", sku: 456, reps: 11, sets: 8, date: "2020/03/06" }
];

const kits = [
  { sku: 123, sets: 2 },
  { sku: 234, sets: 100 },
  { sku: 345, sets: 12 },
  { sku: 456, sets: 3 }
];

const dataMap = res.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.name] ??= {};
  r[o.name][o.date] ??= { sets: 0, reps: 0, total: 0, skus: [] };
  r[o.name][o.date].sets += +o.sets;
  r[o.name][o.date].reps += +o.reps;
  
  //my issues start here
  r[o.name][o.date].skus.push({ [o.sku]: [] });

  const foundBox = kits.find((box) => box.sku === res.sku);
  let status;

  if (foundBox) {
    if (Number(res.sets) > Number(foundBox.sets)) {
      status = "Not available";
    } else {
      status = "Available";
    }
  } else {
    status = "No stock found";
  }

  r[o.name][o.date].skus.push(status);
  r[o.name].total ??= 0;
  r[o.name].total += +o.sets * +o.reps;
  return r;
}, {});

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(dataMap, null, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: `kits.find((box) => box.sku === res.sku);` shouldt be `o.sku` instead of `res.sku`. `res` is the array.

Comment: @VLAZ - inside a reduce, so should be `o.sku` not `r.sku` or `res.sku` - also `Number(res.sets)` should be `Number(o.sets)`

Comment: @VLAZ Ok I do see that now, but it is still printint status outside of the sku array. Where am I going wrong as far as getting the status to be a part of each sku's array

Comment: it's appearing exactly where you're pushing it `r[o.name][o.date].skus.push(status);`

Comment: @Bravo right but if you run the snippet you'll see that it's outside of the sku. I want that first entry to look like "skus": [
                {
                    "123": [ "status":"available"]
                },

Comment: @Bravo so I'm pushing it to the skus level, but not the individual sku level

Comment: `{ "123": [ "status":"available"] }` isn't valid ...

Comment: How would I properly attach the status at each individual sku level then? Right now it gives me two messages for two skus at a single level, I need each status to be a value for it's related sku

Comment: see answer - question got closed, so not sure I can do much about explaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const res = [
  { name: "joe", sku: 123, reps: 2, sets: 2, date: "2020/03/03" },
  { name: "joe", sku: 234, reps: 15, sets: 2, date: "2020/03/03" },
  { name: "joe", sku: 345, reps: 26, sets: 5, date: "2020/03/05" },
  { name: "joe", sku: 456, reps: 11, sets: 8, date: "2020/03/06" }
];

const kits = [
  { sku: 123, sets: 2 },
  { sku: 234, sets: 100 },
  { sku: 345, sets: 12 },
  { sku: 456, sets: 3 }
];

const dataMap = res.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.name] ??= {};
  r[o.name][o.date] ??= { sets: 0, reps: 0, total: 0, skus: [] };
  r[o.name][o.date].sets += +o.sets;
  r[o.name][o.date].reps += +o.reps;
  
  // ***** change following 2 lines
  const x= {};
  r[o.name][o.date].skus.push({[o.sku]:x});

  // ***** no need for else if you initialise the value
  let status = "No stock found";

  const foundBox = kits.find((box) => box.sku === o.sku);

  if (foundBox) {
    if (Number(o.sets) > Number(foundBox.sets)) {
      status = "Not available";
    } else {
      status = "Available";
    }
  // ***** no need, use default above
  //} else {
  //  status = "No stock found";
  }
  // ***** assign the status
  x.status = status;
  r[o.name].total ??= 0;
  r[o.name].total += +o.sets * +o.reps;
  return r;
}, {});

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(dataMap, null, 4) + "</pre>";
```